# nHibernate, OR clause with .withSubquery

Tags: nhibernate, conditional-statements

How can we force nHibernate to  generate “OR” clause instead of “AND” clause when using  “.withSubquery”

```
var includeSharedTemplateCategories= EntityFinder.Of<TemplateMappers.FolderEntity>()       .Where(e => e.MID == effectiveMemberID) .Where(e => e.CategoryType == "shared_template") .SelectList(e => e.Select(c => c.Id));

var includeNormalCategories = EntityFinder.Of<TemplateMappers.FolderEntity>()
.Where(e => e.MID == MemberID)
.Where(e => e.CategoryType == "template")
.SelectList(e => e.Select(c => c.Id));

var query = EntityFinder.Of<TemplateMappers.TemplateEntity>()
.Where(f => f.TemplateIsActive == 1)
.RestrictionByQuery<TemplateMappers.TemplateEntity, TemplateObject>(options)
.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(e => e.CategoryId).In(includeSharedTemplateCategories)
.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(e => e.CategoryId).In(includeNormalCategories)
.SelectByQuery<TemplateMappers.TemplateEntity, TemplateObject>(options)
.OrderByQuery<TemplateMappers.TemplateEntity, TemplateObject>(options);
```

**“And”  is used in condition**

```
this_.fkcategoryid IN (SELECT this_0_.pkcategoryid AS y0_ 
FROM   categories this_0_ 
WHERE  this_0_.mid = xyz AND this_0_.categorytype = 's_template') 
And this_.fkcategoryid IN (SELECT this_0_.pkcategoryid AS y0_ FROM   categories this_0_ 
WHERE  this_0_.mid = abc AND this_0_.categorytype = 'template');
```

**I’m looking for “OR“ clause between sub-queries.**

```
this_.fkcategoryid IN (SELECT this_0_.pkcategoryid AS y0_                                           FROM   categories this_0_ WHERE  this_0_.mid = xyz AND this_0_.categorytype = 's_template') 
**OR**  this_.fkcategoryid IN (SELECT this_0_.pkcategoryid AS y0_ FROM   dbo.tblcategories this_0_ WHERE  this_0_.mid = abc AND this_0_.categorytype = 'template');
```

kris.

Answer (score 1):

```
var includeSharedAndNormalTemplateCategories = EntityFinder.Of<FolderEntity>()
       .Where(e => (e.MID == effectiveMemberID && e.CategoryType == "shared_template") ||
                   (e.MID == MemberID && e.CategoryType == "template"))
       .Select(e => e.Id);

var query = EntityFinder.Of<TemplateEntity>()
    .Where(f => f.TemplateIsActive)
    .RestrictionByQuery<TemplateEntity, TemplateObject>(options)
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(e => e.CategoryId).In(includeSharedAndNormalTemplateCategories)
    .SelectByQuery<TemplateEntity, TemplateObject>(options)
    .OrderByQuery<TemplateEntity, TemplateObject>(options);
```

SideNote: `TemplateIsActive` should be/is bool no?

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Active flag is int
In our system. 

Thx